# Get a JSON data using BeautifulSoup in Python Webscraping

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a JSON object but getting an error, I am using BeautifulSoup.
I can't remove "window.pageData= " to do that perfectly. Also got error using .replace method to replace "window.pageData=" but couldn't succeed.
My Code:

```
    link = "https://www.daraz.com.bd/catalog/?q=" + "Pudina"
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    all_scripts = soup.find_all('script')
    my_script=all_scripts[3]
    jsData = re.search(r'window.pageData=', my_script.text)
    data = json.loads(jsData.group(1))
```

Here is my Script

```
<script>window.pageData={
 "mods": {
   "listItems": [
     {
       "name": "Mint leaf Powder (পুদিনা পাতা গুড়া) (১০০গ্রাম)- Pudina Pata Gura",
       "nid": "125018674",
       "productUrl": "//www.daraz.com.bd/products/mint-leaf-powder-pudina-pata-gura-i125018674-s1045213986.html?search=1",
       "image": "https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/e742aabbea46336304f2081a29de1139.jpg",
       "originalPrice": "180.00",
       "originalPriceShow": "৳ 180",
       "price": "171",
     }
   ]
 }
}</script>
```

Comment: You don't need BeautifulSoup here at all. Try this `print(json.loads(re.findall(r"window\.pageData=(.*?)</",r.text)[0]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what have you tried in `.replace()`, but this works for me.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json
link = "https://www.daraz.com.bd/catalog/?q=" + "Pudina"
r = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
all_scripts = soup.find_all('script')
my_script=all_scripts[3]
my_script = re.sub('window.pageData=', "",my_script.text)
#my_script=my_script.text.replace("window.pageData=","")
#print(my_script)
data = json.loads(my_script)
print(data)
```

Comment: ```raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```      got this error.

Comment: ```in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)``` also ```in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())```

Comment: I've added the whole code if you want including imports, seems to be working perfectly for me. could you let me know the versions of each library or the python version you are using?

Comment: i just now tried with exact your code but got this error, [screenshot](https://pasteboard.co/JrDUNov.png)

Comment: edited my code. could you verify if the ```print(my_script)``` still gives ```window.pageData=```

Comment: wow. seems to be an error with python 3.8. i've got v 3.7.0 and works perfectly. Here's the [screenshot](https://pasteboard.co/JrDXJxv.jpg)

Comment: Great, So I need to switch back to 3.7 ?

Comment: No wait. that would be very hectic. could you try my latest edit? it doesn't use replace. Maybe that'll help